# Parsing the result of a PHP Web Service

Tags: java, php, android, web-services

I'm using a PHP Web Services that I'm consuming on an Android application.

The Web Services inserts data on a database and returns information from it.

How I can parse the result of using that Web Service to avoid errors?

In Android, I execute the post request by this way:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
```

What should I do on the Web Service to process possible errors?

Thanks!

Comment: you´ve got `statusCode` and `statusLine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As eduyayo and Deutro said. You can check status code of your response

`int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();`

List of Status codes - [HttpStatus](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.html) codes and handle exceptions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

On your Server you should return different StatusCodes for different ErrorMessages.
In your client you can check for the error StatusCodes and update your UI according to the error you get.